# Continuous Random Variables: $P(X > a)$ vs $P(X \geq a)$

Tags: probability

For a continuous random variable X, P(X > a) can be calculated by $\displaystyle \int_{ a }^{ \infty } f(x) dx$. Where $f(x)$ is the probability density function. Would this be the same for $P(X \geq a)$ ?

What is the general rule here? One way to find this would be $1 - P(X < a) = 1 - F(a)$. Where $F(a)$ is the distribution function.

In general if a question says something like "within the first 150 hours", I should calculate $P(X < 150)$ or $P(X \leq 150)$, for these, would I still integrate from 0 to 150 for both? Hope its clear what my doubt is.

Can someone explain this? I've managed to confuse myself. Thanks in advance.

Comment: For a continuous random variable $X$ we have $P(X=a)=0$ for any $a$...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Recall that $P(X = a) = 0$. Note that $P(X \geq a) = P(X > a) + P(X = a)$.